# Delegate browser resource loading to a server—caching reverse proxy?

Tags: networking, caching, browser, browser-cache

Could I run a squid proxy for myself on a server, or something, to make resource loading over a high-latency connection more consistent?

Opera was formerly designed to support remote rendering on their servers. My thought is that connections my browser makes through my caching reverse proxy, could quickly load into the cache, and then, I have more control over connections to the proxy, for example HTTP/3.

I was going to ask if this is possible, if I can have chrome run a resource loading delegate daemon on a server, but it seems unlikely that's supported.

I suspect this is all more complexity than I want to endure, just for faster browsing. But if I do gwern-style archiving of what I read, I could imagine investing more in a solution that achieves both archiving and caching.

So the question is: what are the easiest ways, currently, to delegate some resource loading to a remote server, with better latency and loss on connections?